# Safely casting struct pointers

Tags: c++, casting, struct

I had always thought that checking the pointer after casting a void* to a struct* was a valid way to avoid invalid casts. Something like

```
MyStructOne* pStructOne = (MyStructOne*)someVoidPointer;
if(!pStructOne)
   return 0;
```

It appears that this is not the case as I can cast the same data to two different structs and get the same valid address. The program is then happy to populate my struct fields with whatever random data is in there.

**What is a safe way of casting struct pointers?**

I can't use dynamic_cast<> as it's not a class.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Easy. Use C++ instead of `void *`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<>` works with structs. - There is no difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ other that the default accessibility

Comment: @shf301, Don't forget the default inheritance type.

Comment: @shf301, but you still need at least one virtual function to use `dynamic_cast`, and structs don't typically have one.

Comment: dynamic_cast definitely does not work with structs. I got a compile error. Also I can't avoid using a void*. I'm using libev, so my only option is a void*

Comment: Yeah - so libev doesn't provide any validity guarantee. Cast to something more c++ in a safe way and never look back.

Comment: @JoshBrittain: `dynamic_cast` most certainly does work with structs. What it *doesn't* work with are types that have no virtual member functions.

Comment: @JoshBrittain: You and shf301 are talking about slightly different things. In C++ `struct` and `class` are equivalent, with the only difference that the default access specifier is public/private in each case. On the other side, many people use `struct` to refer to POD types (which among other properties don't have virtual functions). It is not legal to use `dynamic_cast` with a class that has no virtual functions regardless of whether the class was created by using the `struct` or `class` keywords.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Regarding *"... but you still need at least one virtual function..."*, is it enough to compile with `-frtti`?

Comment: @jww obviously you need RTTI support, but that's not sufficient on its own. C++ doesn't store any information in the object to determine its type unless there's a virtual function, then you get a vtable pointer or something similar that can be used to derive the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any control over the struct layout you can put your own type enumeration at the front of every struct to verify the type. This works in both C and C++.

If you can't use an enumeration because not all types are known ahead of time, you can use a GUID. Or a pointer to static variable or member that is unique per struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic_cast` with structs or classes, as long as it has a virtual method. I would suggest you redesign your broader system to not have `void*`s anywhere. It's very bad practice/design.

Comment: Can't avoid using a void*. I'm using libev library.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "safe way of casting" in general, because casting pointers is inherently an unsafe procedure. Casting says that you know better than the type system, so you can't expect the type system to be of any help after you started casting pointers.

In C++, you should never use C-style casts (like `(T) x`), and instead use the C++ casts. Now a few simple rules let you determine whether casting a pointer or reference is OK:

- If you `const_cast` in the bad direction and modify the object, you must be sure that the object is actually mutable.
- You can only `static_cast` pointers or references within a polymorphic hierarchy or from/to void pointer. You must be sure that the dynamic type of the object is a subtype of the cast target, or in the case of void pointers that pointer is the address of an object of the correct type.
- `reinterpret_cast` should only be used to or from a `char *` type (possibly `signed` or `unsigned`), or to convert a pointer to and from an `(u)intptr_t`.

In every case, it is *your* responsibility to ensure that the pointers or references in question refer to an object of the type that you claim in the cast. There is no check that anyone else can do for you to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

The (C-style) cast you are using is compile-time operation  - that is to say that the compiler generates instructions to modify the pointer to one thing so that it points to another.

With inheritance relationships, this is simply addition or subtraction from the pointer.

In the case of your code, the compiler generates precisely *no code* whatsoever.  The cast merely serves to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing.

The compiler does not generate any code that checks the validity of your operation. If `someVoidPointer` is null, so will be `pStructOne` after the cast. \

Using a `dynamic_cast<>()` doesn't validate that the thing being casted is actually an object at all - it merely tells you that an object with RTTI is (or can be converted to) the type you expect.  If it's not an object to start with, you'll most likely get a crash.

Comment: I should clarify that the compile error of dynamic_cast is when using it on a void*. It looks like I may have to redesign so that the void* is either null or ONLY one type at all times.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. And frankly, there can't be.

`struct` is simply an instruction for the compiler to treat the next `sizeof()` bytes in a particular semantic fashion - nothing less, nothing more.

You can cast any pointer into any pointer - all that changes is how the compiler would interpret the contents.

Using `dynamic_cast<>` is the only way, but it invokes RTTI (run type type information) to consider the potential legality of the assignment. Yeah, it's no longer an `reinterpret_cast<>`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make sure the object passed as a `void*` to your function is really the type you expect. The best approach would be to declare the function prototype with `MyStructOne*` instead of `void*` and let the compiler do the type checking.

If you really are trying to do something more dynamic (as in different types of objects can be passed to your function) you need to enable [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information%5d). This will allow you to interrogate the passed in object and ask it what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

> What is a safe way of casting struct pointers?

First, try to avoid *needing* to do this in the first place. Use forward declarations for structs if you don't want to include their headers. In general, you should only need to hide the data type from the signature if a function could take *multiple* types of data. The example for something like that is a message passing system, where you want to be able to pass arbitrary data. The sender and receiver know what types they expect, but the message system itself doesn't need to know.

Assuming you have no other alternatives, use a [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html). This is essentially a type-safe `void*`; attempts to cast it to the wrong type will throw an exception. Note that this needs RTTI to work (which you generally should have available).

Note that `boost::variant` is a possibility if there is a fixed, limited set of possible types that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to use `void*`, your options are:

1. create a single base class including a virtual destructor (and/or other virtual methods) and use that exclusively across the libev interface. Wrap the libev interface to enforce this, and only use the wrappers from your C++ code. Then, *inside* your C++ code, you can `dynamic_cast` your base class.
2. accept that you don't have any runtime information about what type your `void*` really points to, and just structure your code so you *always* know statically. That is, make sure you cast to the correct type in the first place.
3. use the `void*` to store a simple tag/cookie/id structure, and use that to look up your real struct or whatever - this is really just a more manual version of #1 though, and incurs an extra indirection to boot.

---

And the direct answer to

> What is a safe way of casting struct pointers?

is:

> cast to the correct type, or a type you know to be layout compatible.

There just isn't any substitute for knowing *statically* what the correct type is. You presumably passed *something* in as a `void*`, so when you get that `void*` back you should be able to know what type it was.